# Continuity of multiplication in algebras over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

friends! Let $X$ be a topological vector space equipped with the structure of an algebra over the field $\mathbb{C}$.

Is the multiplication $X\times X\to X ,(x,y)\mapsto xy$ continuous with respect to the product topology of $X\times X$ for generical topological vector space or, at least, for normed ones? If it is, could anybody so kind to give a proof or a link to a proof?

Thank you all!!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know the definition of a tvs as a vector space with a topological structure such that $X\times X\to X,(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $\mathbb{C}\times X\to X,(\lambda,x)\mapsto \lambda x$ are continuous.

Comment: More to the point, how do you define topological algebra? A typical definition requires continuity of multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for the very interesting point! My book of functional analysis seems to use the fact that multiplication is continuous without defining topological algebras, but only normed algebras. So, I see that continuity must be included in a more general definition. Anyhow, if $X$ is normed, I would say that multiplication is continuous, isn't that so? $\infty$ thanks!

Comment: Thank you too!!! If $X$ is a normed algebra, it is a topological algebra with continuous multiplication: is that so?

Comment: @copper.hat There are two kinds of multiplication. You are talking about multiplication by a scalar, the OP is asking about multiplication of two elements.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Sorry about that, I missed that completely. I was thinking topological group. I will delete my comments.